# Wie nennt man eine zusammengefügte Zeichnung in einem Textverarbeitungsprogramm?

Tags: single-word-request, technical-terminology

In Textverarbeitungsprogrammen wie z.B. LibreoOffice Writer und Microsoft Word kann man sogenannte Formen oder Shapes (Linien, Pfeile, Sprechblasen, geometrische Figuren, ...) in ein Dokument einfügen. Bei Bedarf kann man mehrere solche Formen auch gruppieren oder zusammenführen. Wie nennt man das Ergebnis einer solchen Zusammenstellung?

- eine zusammengeführte Grafik / Zeichnung?
- eine kombinierte Grafik / Zeichnung?
- eine zusammengestellte Grafik / Zeichnung?

Ich dachte zuerst an "Gesamt-Zeichnung", aber dieses Wort hat eine [spezifische technische Bedeutung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_199#Gesamt-Zeichnungen), die nicht übereinstimmt mit der, die ich suche. Gibt es bessere Alternativen?

---

Der gesuchte Begriff wird in einem Kontext benutzt, in dem der Unterschied zwischen "normalen" Grafiken, einzelne Formen und "<del>zusammengeführte</del> *zusammengefügte* Zeichnungen" relevant ist.

Comment: Was ist denn das Ergebnis der Gruppierung / Zusammenführung? Sind die Elemente weiterhin eigenständig ( und man kann sie etwa noch verschieben ) oder ergibt das ganze eine neue (Gesamt-)Zeichnung in der die einzelnen Elemente aufgehen? Oder wird ein Begriff für sowohl das eine als auch das andere gesucht?

Answer (score 4):

Das Ergebnis einer Gruppierung ist einfach eine Gruppe. Das ist in allen Programmen für die Bearbeitung von Vektor-Grafiken (und auch in der 3D-Modellierung) eine gängige Operation und jeder Kundige wird wissen und verstehen was damit gemeint ist.

Hier ein Beispiel der Verwendung auf supportnet.de: [Gruppieren von Objekten in Inkscape](https://supportnet.de/gruppieren-von-objekten-in-inkscape5794/)

Den Begriff "zusammenführen" habe ich übrigens in diesem Zusammenhang glaube ich nie gehört. Achte darauf, dass man Vektor-Grafiken "zusammenfügen" kann, was aber eine andere Bedeutung hat als "gruppieren". Kann es sein, dass du zusammenführen und zusammenfügen verwechselst?

Comment: Stimme voll zu. Bin Programmierer und arbeite viel mit Vektorgrafiken und Programmen zum Diagramme-Zeichnen wie Microsoft Visio. Man gruppiert mehrere "primitive" (= kleinere, einfachere) Elemente einer Grafik, um sie gemeinsam zu bearbeiten, z. B. gemeinsam zu verschieben oder gleichmäßig zu vergrößern. Dieses "Zusammenfassen" nennt man immer **gruppieren**  und das Resultat ist stets eine **Gruppe**. Im SVG-Dateiformat heißt das entsprechende Element sogar <g> für "group", siehe  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g.

Comment: "Zusammenführen" habe ich auf [Chip.de](https://praxistipps.chip.de/word-objekte-gruppieren-so-gehts_34981) und [Office.com](https://support.office.com/de-de/article/Zeichnen-Sie-ein-Bild-indem-Sie-kombinieren-und-Zusammenf%C3%BChren-von-shapes-2c9ce121-7b28-46ed-aec9-eae20cdddb15) gefunden.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Beachte, dass der Artikel auf Office.com automatisch übersetzt worden ist. In der "richtig" übersetzten Software (PowerPoint) wird der Begriff so nicht verwendet.

Answer (score 1):

Vermutlich gibt es im Computer-Jargon einen Spezialbegriff für genau diese Art von gruppierten Formen, aber aus der Sicht eines Lesers, der das gedruckte oder auf Folien präsentierte Endprodukt betrachtet, ist es einfach eine

## Abbildung

Für den Betrachter ist es irrelevant, auf welche Weise eine Abbildung zuwegegebracht wurde. Deshalb werden Abbildungen in Texten auch immer Abbildung genannt, nicht "gruppierte Formen" oder "Tortendiagramm" oder "Verteilungskurve". Dies kann dann Teil der *Beschreibung der Abbildung* sein, ist aber nicht mehr deren Bezeichnung. Z.B.:

> [image]
>
> Abb. 1. Gruppierte Formen.

Comment: Danke, aber den Begriff, den ich suche, ist für ein technisches Dokument (also für Autoren) gedacht.

Comment: Das war aus der Frage nicht ersichtlich. Wie löscht man denn eine Antwort?

Comment: Man klickt auf "flag" und wählt "In need of moderator intervention"; wenn ich mich recht erinnere, kann man dann angeben, dass man die Antwort löschen will.

Comment: da sollte unter der Antwort ein "delete" Schriftzug sein. Denn eigene Antworten löschen ist m.E. von Reputation unabhängig. In Bildverarbeitungsprogrammen ist der Begriff "Gruppierung" - was allerdings einfach meint, dass verschiedene Objekte gemeinsam "bewegt" werden.

Comment: Shegit hat recht, man kann eigene Antworten immer löschen oder auch editieren, egal wieviel (oder wenig) Reputation man hat.

Answer (score 1):

Zeichnung vs. Plan / Skizze

Im technischen Bereich gibt es zwei grundsätzlich verschiedene Arten von Abbildungen.

**Zeichnung** (Metallbau, Hoch-Tiefbau, etc / Ansichtszeichnung, Bohrschema etc.)
Eine Zeichnung ist grundsätzlich maßstäblich und exakt beschriftet.
Also alles was man nutzen kann um ein exakt definiertes Werkstück herzustellen.
Deswegen sind Zeichnungen stark formalisiert und für ausgebildete Fachleute eindeutig interpretierbar. Zudem sind dann viele Maße und Angaben eingetragen oder mindestens referenziert. Oftmals werden auf Normen verwiesen für Detailangaben.
Oder eine Gesammtzeichnung verweist in einzelnen Bereichen auf Detailzeichnungen.

**Plan / Skizze etc** (Schaltplan
Ein Plan ist eher da um Funktionen oder Zusammenhänge dazustellen.
Ein Schaltplan z. B. kann verschieden aufgebaut werden, aber die Funktion ist gleich.
Ein UML-Schema kann komplett verschieden aussehen, aber die Funktion sollte das gleiche Ergebnis ergeben.

Comment: "Der gesuchte Begriff wird in einem Kontext benutzt, in dem der Unterschied zwischen "normalen" Grafiken, einzelne Formen und "zusammengeführte Zeichnungen" relevant ist." - deswegen -1

Comment: Christophe Strobbe hatte im Konnentar oben geschrieben, dass es ein technisches Dokument sein soll.

Und in technischen Dokumenten wird generell unterschieben zwischen Zeichnungen (maßstäblich und präzise) und anderen Abbildungen.

Eine Graphik nenn ich in meinen Dokumentationen etc. immer Graphik, egal ob ich sie auch in Teilen woanders angebildet habe.

Answer (score 1):

Bei der Beantwortung der Frage ist wichtig, ob du die Semantik oder die Syntax meinst?

Wenn es die Semantik ist, dann würde ich Collage oder Komposition verwenden.

Wenn die Syntax gemeint ist, dann wird es schwierig und lässt sich so allgemein gültig kaum zusammen fassen bzw. ausdrücken. Auch hier sind natürlich rein syntaktisch gesehen die obigen Begriffe anwendbar. Um das aber einordnen zu können, ist immer wichtig zu betonen, ob eine Bedeutung mit der Sammlung/Zusammenstellung ausgedrückt werden soll oder nicht.